# Why does my remote repo increase in size after bfg clean up?

Tags: git, bfg-repo-cleaner

Used BFG to clean repo with large files.

I tried to follow step from bfg [tutorial page](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/).

Steps I followed:

`git clone --mirror myrepo.git`

`java -jar bfg-1.13.0.jar --no-blob-protection --delete-folders "{large_folder}" test_repo.git`

`git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive`

`git push`

The `git push` did not worked for me I had to change `denyNonFastforwards = true` to `denyNonFastforwards = false` in my remote repo's config file.

So the problem I am having is the local repo size get shrunk but when I push to the **remote remote** repo size increase.

The strange thing is when I `clone --mirror` that **remote repo** locally and see the size, it actually is small.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to run 'git gc' on the remote repo too, which will trigger a collection of the now unused git objects.

More commonly, users have a git hosting service like GitHub as their remote, and the hosting service will periodically run 'git gc' for the users.

When you clone from a remote, only the essential data is sent- so you get only get the cleaned history, even if the remote repo has a bunch of unused git data lying around.

Comment: I had created a git bare repo in another desktop. So I when to that directory and did `git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive` and it worked. Thank you!!

Comment: I dont understand this solution nor the reply. From what I know is not possible to run git gc on remote and doing `git reflog expire --expire=now --all && git gc --prune=now --aggressive` reduces size locally but not in remote :S